# How to attach claw feet to cast iron bath

Tags: bathroom, bathroom-fixtures

[image: Bottom of bath]Trying to attach the feet to our victorian bathtub is turning out to be more challenging than we initially thought. I have looked online, so far none of the baths seem to have the exact fitting we do, there is no space for a bolt to sit to slide the foot onto to secure it. We have tried securing the feet with a metal plate and a bolt but they slide out when we move the bath which does not inspire confidence with how secure they would be.

Comment: Thank you for including a picture, that's very helpful. Unfortunately, it's not well lit and it's hard to tell exactly what we're looking at. It's hard to know if that nearly black area in the center of that bulge is a screw for threading the foot on to, or a hole for threading the foot in to, or something else. If you could try a picture with the flash on to light that up some, it might help. Additionally, a picture of the connection part of the foot, and how the two look together when you've got them connected the way you've tried would be most helpful. Just [edit] them into your question.

Comment: If this is a vintage tub there is a good chance that part of the original foot securing mechanism has broken off.  Do all 4 corners look _exactly_ the same?

Comment: Or it may be a screwless design that is only intended to stay put by gravity, with the tub sitting still in one spot, as tubs normally do. Moving the tub is not a normal thing once it's properly in place and attached to pipes. Pictures of the foot side of this connection, as well as a better tub-side picture or pictures, might shed some light on this question.